# How to find out which lib require this dependency in Node

Tags: node.js

All:

I am currently using Express.js to build web app, but when I start it, it keeps posting some console messages like:

```
GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1472255616254 404 505.126 ms - 916
```

I wonder if there is a simple way to find out which module file cause this, this is just too annoying.

The library I required into includes:

```
express
d3
fs
path
colors
lodash
```

It seems due to Express, cos when I create another brnad new express app, this message still shown up.

Thanks

Comment: Questions about code MUST include the relevant code.

Comment: `npm i sockjs --save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan). Probably, you have something like this in your code:

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```